# Best way to implement mongoose multiuser room unread status

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have `Room` model like this:

```
var ReadSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  admins: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  }],
  users: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  }],
});
```

And now I need to implement unread messages count for each user in this room. I decided to store UserId/LatestReadedMessageId for each user. How I can do it?

It think about object with UserId as key and MessageId as value:

```
var RoomSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  admins: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  }],
  users: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  }],
  reads: [{
    user: {
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    latest: Date
  }],
});
```

But I think it's not the best idea.

What will advise? thank you